# TextChannel returning null after creation

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

when i create a text channel and add a memberpermissionoverride then try to get it after it created the channel it returns null.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Anyway, here's the code.

```
shinto.createTextChannel(p.getName() + "-verify").addMemberPermissionOverride(trueDiscordMember.getIdLong(), ticketPermissionsAllow, ticketPermissionsDeny).addMemberPermissionOverride(bot.getJDA().getSelfUser().getIdLong(), botAllow, Collections.emptyList()).queue();
                        
                        TextChannel channel = bot.getJDA().getTextChannelsByName(p.getName() + "-verify", true).get(0);
```

Any help is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're using `queue` so the action happens async but you're trying to get the `TextChannel` instantly so basically, you're trying to get it before it is created.

To solve that you can do either of these two examples:

```
guild.createTextChannel("stuff" + "-verify").queue(textChannel -> {
    //DO STUFF
});
```

In this example, I'm using `RestAction#queue(Consumer)` which means it'll execute the consumer (the consumer parameter will be the `TextChannel` that was created) once the action is complete and it'll run async. In this example, you avoid blocking the thread.

---

```
TextChannel channel = guild.createTextChannel("stuff" + "-verify").complete();
```

In this example, I'm using `RestAction#complete()` which means it'll return the channel and it'll block the thread until the action is complete.

---

Read more about RestAction here: https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/RestAction.html